# How can I watch movies offline on my Android tablet?

Tags: video, asus-eee-pad-transformer, 3.2-honeycomb, offline

How can I watch movies on my tablet (Asus Transformer tablet with Android 3.2) offline?

I recognize that this is a very basic question, however, I can not find any step-by-step instructions on this site or online. It is also not clear if any popular sites such as Netflix, Amazon, or Hulu support offline viewing. I think that it would be useful to have step-by-step instructions.

If I had the tablet in my hands, I would probably be able to figure something out - even though it is a new device and my first experience with Android. However, my wife has taken it and the children on a trip, and would like to use it for entertainment on the flight home.

Comment: This site is for questions about use of Android, not shopping suggestions. How/where to get movies has nothing to do with Android.

Comment: @Chahk I have an android, and I would to watch movies on it - I want to know how I can do so. I have revised the question for clarity.

Comment: Try searching the Market for movie player apps; you will find plenty.  As far as content, your choices are more limited.  You can try ripping your DVD/Blue Ray library to files (not legal in some countries,) or searching the Internet for other legal download sources.  You can also try various online rental services, such as Android Market, Amazon Video, Blockbuster, etc.  Although some only offer online streaming, there are several that allow you to download rented movies and TV shows (with DRM protection) for offline viewing.  Listing them here would be counter-productive though.

Comment: To close voters: This is a valid question for this site: how to download and watch movies on an Android device. @David: Asking for "recommendations" is a good way to get your question closed, as it looks like you're just asking "what's your favorite X" which is off-topic for this site and any site in the Stack Exchange network. You might want to re-word your question.

Comment: @AlEverett thank you for the feedback. I have changed the second part of the question to address this issue.

Comment: Can you please tell us what tablet and what Android version you are running? It will go a long way as the recommendations will differ depending on these factors

Comment: @GauthamC I have edited my question to include this information

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Android comes with a basic video player called "Movies", although it might not show in the application list for some devices. To use the built-in player, you need to use the Gallery or a file manager to invoke the Movies app on the movie file you want to play.

Alternatively there are many alternative movie players on the Market. Here are a few threads to get you started:

- [MX Video Player](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5teHRlY2gudmlkZW9wbGF5ZXIuYWQiXQ..)
- [MoboPlayer](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.clov4r.android.nil&hl=en)
- [RockPlayer](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.redirectin.rockplayer.android.unified.lite&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5yZWRpcmVjdGluLnJvY2twbGF5ZXIuYW5kcm9pZC51bmlmaWVkLmxpdGUiXQ..)
- [QQPlayer](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.tencent.research.drop&feature=search_result)
- [VPlayer](https://market.android.com/details?id=me.abitno.vplayer.t&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsIm1lLmFiaXRuby52cGxheWVyLnQiXQ..)

Answer (score 2):

[DroidTV Primetime](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.PersonalDVR.Subscription) is the one that I find most useful. I was hoping to use Netflix or LoveFilm on a tablet - even if I had to go iPad - but offline viewing seems fundamental to the nature of these devices and yet completely unsupported.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is similar to the one in this thread:

[Asus Transformer video playback](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17489/asus-transformer-video-playback/17519#17519)

To reiterate, make sure to download the codec pack from inside the app if you are using MoboPlayer. When you first install and open the app, there are two options, one to install the codec packs directly from the web or from the market. I find choosing the former works best.

Answer (score 1):

I am using VUDU for my offline viewing on my Samsung tablet. I am a newbie at this. I downloaded a few movies and then also used VUDU to download my UltraViolet movie.  it seems to work. my tablet is a little slow at first, basically thought it wasn't working then it popped up.
Flying to Hawaii later, long boring sardine style flight so I hope it works...

Answer (score 0):

Or just buy them on DVD and use a program like Handbrake or [iFunia DVD Ripper](http://www.ifunia.com/dvd-ripper-mac.html) to rip them to the tablet.