# Asus Transformer video playback

Tags: video, asus-eee-pad-transformer

I have an Asus Transformer tablet with the dock extesion and I am trying to play a video file recorded in MOV format. I had recorded the video on my Powershot ELPH 310HS camera in 1080p setting and it is saved in h264 format.

I tried putting the SD card into the dock and playg back the video but the playback is very slow and I think it i sbeing done in software.I installed the MX video player app to play back the video.

My question is if there is any way to do playback using a HW  video decoder? I thik that I've read that the tegra 2 has this bultin but I don't know enough about video formats to know whether this is a hardware limitation or whether it could be solved with a diffferent app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mobo Player. Singlehandedly the best video player app on Android. Its the 'VLC' of Android. Plays nearly every format flawlessly.

Download the app, click the button to download a 2MB codec pack (so it can play different video formats) and you are good to go. If you have any problem with the playback, just go into the settings and force software rendering.

https://market.android.com/details?id=com.clov4r.android.nil&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5jbG92NHIuYW5kcm9pZC5uaWwiXQ..

Comment: I installed it, then the the codec.  And now when I launch it, I get sent to the Market app, showing the Mobo app, with Open and uninstall.  So open takes me back to the Market app.  Very odd.